# Heap corruption detected when use delete

Tags: c++

i run this code and got this exception in visual studio:

```
int main ()
{
int * x=new int(23);
for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
{
    x[i]=i;
}
delete []x;
return(0);
}
```

thanks for your help ;)

Comment: Shouldn't this be `int* x = new int[23];`

Comment: you likely want new int[23] (square brackets)

Comment: Yep, the way you wrote it, you assigned the value 23 to a single integer.

Comment: no ,allocated but when arrive to delete line give me heap exception.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is simple error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int * x = new int(23);` does not do what you think. It allocates the memory for a int and gives it the value of 23.

What you want to do is this:

```
int * x = new int[23];
```

Although, I would recommend you use [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) if the size change or [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) if the size is fix.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `new` you need to use `delete`.  If you use `new[]` then you need to use `delete []`.  `new()` is not the same as `new[]`.  `new(someval)` sets the new object to someval.  It does not make someval number of objects.